# Arms detatching from torso on character rig? (rigify)

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

i've been working on this model for a while now and just started rigging it with rigify. However, i've run into an error i've never come across before, and i'm not sure how to fix it. I've been having all sorts of deformation problems with the arms from them just looking downright weird when turning them upwards, to them straight up disconnecting from the torso when I rotate it. How can I fix this? I've provided the blend file below. Thank you for your assistance!
image of issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eedu1.jpg
Blend file: [image]

Comment: hello, we need an authorization to download your file, please share it here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @moonboots My bad! thank you, i've uploaded it to the site you mentioned. Sorry, i'm new to stack exchange haha

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I combined the torso and arms into one mesh, and connected the shirt with the arms. Now it works! Yay!

Comment: Nice, yeah seems like the Auto Weights didn't do a good job with the way your model was modeled.